# MySQL Constraint for Unique Values

Tags: mysql, sql, database, constraints, unique

How would you go about creating a table with a constraint in MySQL that only applies to 1 particular table where you want 1 field to be unique for each unique record?

For example, let's say that I have a table called "person" with the following fields:

1. person_social_security (primary key)
2. person_id
3. person_name
4. person_phone_extension

For each record, I want to make sure that field #3 (**person_phone_extension**) is also always unique for every **person_id**. In other words, a **person_id** should never have a duplicate **person_phone_extension**. However, a different **person_id** can have the same **person_phone_extension** as another **person_id**. There can be multiple instances of **person_id** in this table.

Comment: if `person_id` is not unique it can not be `primary key`

Comment: True. Changed the example to correct that mistake.

Comment: If I understand you, you can have multiple records with the same person_id, so what does that column represent?

Answer (score 2):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/df732/2

just set `UNIQUE KEY` against your column:

```
create table person (
person_id int auto_increment primary key,
person_name varchar(50),
person_phone_extension int unique key);
```

using my fiddle you can see if you uncomment my last query that will bring mysql error about duplicate value.

**UPDATE** According to your new comments `person_id` is not primary key and not unique. But combination of `person_id`+`person_phone_extension` should be checked. So you need to set a key against those 2 columns like:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/51547/1

```
create table person (
person_id int,
person_name varchar(50),
person_phone_extension int,
unique key idx (person_id,person_phone_extension));
```

Comment: This SQL fiddle site is awesome for testing things out!

Though this isn't quite what I was looking for. Each person_id cannot have a duplicate person_phone_extension, but a different person_id can have the same person_phone_extension. I'll edit my original question to be a little more clear on that.